# Encryption broken since adding 64bit support to iOS app

Tags: ios, encryption, 64-bit

I use the following code for encryption in my app. I have just changed my app to have the required 64bit support that Apple wants. Since enabling 64bit, encryption no longer works. I cannot tell if there is something wrong with encrypt or decrypt, but when encrypting some data and then decrypting it, I just end up with garbage.

```
#import "AES256.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@implementation NSData (AES256)

- (NSData*)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString*)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted    = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData*)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString*)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted    = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

@end
```

**UPDATE:**
I have have found a problem with my key that may be part of the reason. Part of the key creation uses a hashed string. This hashing function is resulting in a different digest value when on a 32bit iPhone as opposed to a 64bit iPhone. I don't know why this is though. The keydata length is never longer than a 32bit integer. If I hard code a string to return here, encrypt/decrypt still doesn't work so there is also still a problem with that.

```
+ (NSString *)hashString:(NSString *)string
{
    const char *s = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];

    // This is the destination
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
    // This one function does an unkeyed SHA1 hash of your hash data
    CC_SHA1(keyData.bytes, (CC_LONG)keyData.length, digest);

    // Now convert to NSData structure to make it usable again
    NSData *convertedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    // description converts to hex but puts <> around it and spaces every 4 bytes
    NSString *hash = [convertedData description];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    return hash;
}
```

**Update 2:** I have noticed that there is only a problem when using data that is less than 16 bytes. 16 and greater works.

Comment: Does it still work when run on 32-bit devices? If so, debug on both types of devices (32-bit and 64-bit) and see at what point you get different results/values.

Comment: Is the key exactly 32 bytes long? Encrypt and decrypt in both 32 & 64 bit modes and `NSLog()` the data and key before and after each operation to narrow down the error. Obviously the Common Crypto functions are not broken.

Comment: Still no hex dump data for us to see, 32 and 64 bit. If you want help you are going to have to do your part of presenting information.

Comment: What do you want to see a hex dump off?

Answer (score 1):

Check **all** the inputs to the encryption methods in 32 bit and 64 bit: Key, IV, plaintext.  Ensure that they are **byte-for-byte** the same.  Track back any differences and fix them.  Crypto is designed to give big output differences for small input differences.

At some point the system change has probably introduced an unexpected change in one of the inputs.

You say that the entire output is garbage; in that case look first at the key.  A faulty IV will only mangle the first 16 bytes in AES.  I am surprised that you do not get a faulty padding error if the output is mangled.

Answer (score 0):

Use This,

```
#import "NSString+MD5Addition.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

@implementation NSString(MD5Addition)

- (NSString *) stringFromMD5{

    if(self == nil || [self length] == 0)
        return nil;

    const char *value = [self UTF8String];

    unsigned char outputBuffer[CC_MD5_BLOCK_BYTES];
    CC_MD5(value, strlen(value), outputBuffer);

    NSMutableString *outputString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:CC_MD5_BLOCK_BYTES * 2];
    for(NSInteger count = 0; count < CC_MD5_BLOCK_BYTES; count++){
        [outputString appendFormat:@"%02x",outputBuffer[count]];
    }

    return outputString;
}
```

Comment: Why a Category, this is not really a string method.